# TV series about a man living in a mansion with a ghost

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember a very short-lived US television series that was broadcast in the early 1990's or late 1980's. It featured a man that moved into a large mansion or castle that happened to be occupied by the ghost of a man that was killed there in the distant past. The man and the ghost became friends, with the ghost frequently helping out or sometimes causing problems - in this respect the show resembled a sitcom and probably is classified as such.

The ghost was unable to leave the mansion for any length of time, or shadowy creatures would attack and try to consume his soul. This may have been due to a curse or something along those lines; I really can't remember. I do recall one specific episode where where the ghost and the man needed to travel somewhere in a small speedboat, while the man used a special kind of vacuum cleaner to suck up the creatures coming after his friend.

This is a bit of a long-shot, but I have exhausted every other resource I can think of for this. It's such a bizarre show, and I can clearly remember watching it in a time slot after Perfect Strangers, but I can't remember any of the characters' names or much of anything else besides what I have provided. I know there were not many episodes made, and I suppose it is possible that it was actually a miniseries.

If anyone can help me out, I'd really appreciate it. This has been driving me crazy for years, and I would hate to think this weird show is a figment of my imagination masquerading as a memory.

Comment: What country were you in (was this an American show? British? etc)

Comment: @phantom42 The very first sentence of my question establishes that this show was broadcast in the US.

Comment: Sorry. Not sure how I missed that. I need to not read these questions while doing other things.

Comment: @phantom42 No worries. Sorry if I came across as snarky in my comment :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like "[The 100 Lives of Black Jack Savage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_100_Lives_of_Black_Jack_Savage)"

> The series followed the story of Black Jack Savage (played by Steven Williams - Stoney Jackson in the pilot), the ghost of a legendary 17th-century Caribbean pirate who teams up with Barry Tarberry (played by Daniel Hugh Kelly), a crooked Wall Street con artist who has escaped trial by coming to the Caribbean. Facing eternal damnation, both of them discover that they need to save 100 lives to compensate for the damage done by their sinful lives, and thus save their own souls.
>
> Any time Black Jack tries to leave the safety of his castle haunt on San Pietro Island, he is fair game for the "snarks". They are entities that can transport Jack to Hell through an entrance at the base of the tree where he was originally hanged. Tarberry has his own difficulties dodging the government agents sent to extradite him back to the United States to stand trial for his crimes. Other characters on San Pietro include the corrupt governor-general, Abel Vasquez (played by Bert Rosario), with whom Tarberry is able to make another deal, and island activist Danielle (played by Roma Downey), who is constantly trying to help protect the locals from the effects of Vasquez's corruption and is not above enlisting Tarberry's help in doing so.
>
> The show follows the misadventures of both Black Jack and his human counterpart as they team up to dodge the law, both supernatural and secular, to make their 100 soul quota and thus win their way to salvation. Each episode ended with a graphic telling the viewers "??? Lives To Go..."

Comment: Incredible. This is without a doubt the show I was talking about. I am so relieved that I did not imagine this!